# Reading Values from Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I populate values from my gridview in my table using this Code:

```
Table table = new Table();

 // get gridlines from gridview
table.GridLines = GridView1.GridLines;

if (GridView1.HeaderRow != null)
{
    table.Rows.Add(GridView1.HeaderRow);
}

foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

if (GridView1.FooterRow != null)
{
    table.Rows.Add(GridView1.FooterRow);
}
```

What I need is to read every data from the table which contains the values of the gridview into an Excel worksheet cell.
How can I achieve this?

PS:  This is my worksheet obj in code-behind in C#.

```
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
     Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
```

Or Is there any other way to add the data from GridView to something else than, using table, which can be easily read?

Comment: Just FYI since you are using ASP.NET: Automating Microsoft Office using COM-Interop on a Windows Server is not (officially) supported by Microsoft, and generally is also very prone to errors (for example when 2 users try generating a file at the same time). You should maybe consider switching to OpenXML, EPPlus or some other similar library.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void ExportToExcel()
    {
        var Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        XlReferenceStyle RefStyle = Excel.ReferenceStyle;
        Excel.Visible = true;
        Workbook wb = null;
        string path = "yourpath";
        try
        {
            wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add(path); 
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex) 
        { 
            throw new Exception(ex.Message); 
        }
        Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1) as Worksheet ;
        for (int j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; ++j)
        {
            (ws.Cells[1, j + 1] as Range).Value2 = GridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText;
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; ++i) 
            {
                object Val = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
                if (Val != null)
                    (ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] as Range).Value2 = Val.ToString();
            }
        }
        Excel.ReferenceStyle = RefStyle;
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject((object)Excel);         
        GC.GetTotalMemory(true); 
    }
```

Yes, there is a number of ways depending of what you gonna do. In your case the easiest one is CSV file (that would be work with Excel excellent). And there is no need to do somethins with DataGridView, if you have a DataSource

Comment: its showing an error in line :
object Val = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
Error: System doesnt contain a definition for Value, are u missing any assembly..

Comment: My example is for version 12.0.0.0 of **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel**. It works fine, I just checked. Well I'm not sure I got it about the loop explanation... Just a loop on DataGridView Rows and Columns